# OpenCart - Build to Order

Tags: ecommerce

I'm trying to build a little store based on OpenCart. The core function I'm trying to achieve is to allow customers to build their own product from a selection of components, unlike those T-shirt DIY with custom images etc.

The closest match I've come with is something like this:
http://test3.breakdesigns.net/index.php/product-builder2

However, there are 2 problems with this:

1. It is built for Joomla, not OpenCart (for some reasons we have to stick with OpenCart, sorry)
2. We are not selling computers so customer may select multiple items from within a single product category. I.e. customer may select 2 cases and each case may add multiple numbers.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.